# Lubuntu - Desktop Preferences error ¨Desktop Manager Not Active¨

Tags: dual-boot, lubuntu

I have recently installed Lubuntu on a Dell Latitude 2110. It is dualboot alongside Windows 7 Professional. I want to change the desktop background, but I can´t seem to figure out how. I tried going into the menu > Preferences > Desktop Preferences. But when I click ¨Desktop Preferences¨ it gives a error message that says ¨Desktop Manager is not Active.¨ Are there any ways to change the desktop background?

```
lsb_release -a

No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS
Release:    18.04
Codename:   bionic
```

Comment: In a normal Lubuntu 18.04 installation, the desktop is managed by the file manager PCManFM. Did you do something to change this? Perhaps you changed the default file manager?  Anyway, you can set pcmanfm to manage the desktop with the command `pcmanfm --desktop`.

Comment: @OrganicMarble Thank you, this fixed the problem! Desktop Preferences works perfectly now and I have successfully changed the wallpaper.

Comment: I'm glad it helped! I'll post it as an answer now and if you like you can accept it by clicking the checkmark.

Answer (score 2):

In a normal Lubuntu 18.04 installation, the desktop is managed by the file manager PCManFM. Did you do something to change this? Perhaps you changed the default file manager?  Anyway, you can set pcmanfm to manage the desktop with the command `pcmanfm --desktop`.

Comment: just crashed/ended process of hanging File Manager (pcmanfm), also desktop (icons) got killed. Thanks for your answer:
pcmanfm --desktop
fixed it.